# Type 'xx' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Iterable<any> | > (Iterable<any> & any[]) | (any[] & Iterable<any>)'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting the following error. I have been trying to resolve this issue for sometime now but with no luck. Can someone please help me out.

> Type 'Student' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Iterable |
> (Iterable & any[]) | (any[] & Iterable)'. Type 'Student' is
> not assignable to type 'any[] & Iterable'. Type 'Student' is not
> assignable to type 'any[]'.

[The Code can be found here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8qsyqg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let stu of studentSelected; let i = index;">
  <tr>
    <td>{{stu.f}} :</td>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let s of stu.ff">
      <td>{{s.s_name}}</td>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from './student.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  studentSelected: Student | any = {
    f: 'dfd',
    ff: [
      {
        s_name: 'nswq'
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

**School.model.ts**

```
export class School {
  s_name: string;

  constructor(s_name: string = '') {
    this.s_name = s_name;
  }
}
```

**student.model.ts**

```
import { School } from './School.model';

export class Student {
  f: string;
  ff: School[];

  constructor(f: string = '', ff: [] = []) {
    this.f = f;
    this.ff = ff;
  }
}
```

Comment: any[] expects at least an array, Student is an object. You need to add `| any`

Comment: @tom10271 But still I don't see the output from the html file. help.

Comment: Please put the relevant code as codeblocks in your question. This question becomes useless if (when!) the link dies.

Comment: @AJT82 I have added the relevant code blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, `selectedStudent` is an object, so remove the outer ngFor. Also, remove all `any` from the code. There is no use to code with TypeScript if you are going to use `any`. So, remove `any` and just declare the variable as a type of `Student`:

```ts
studentSelected: Student = {
  f: 'dfd',
  ff: [
    {
      s_name: 'nswq'
    }
  ]
};
```

I see you are using classes with constructor. Please note that how you are declaring your `studentSelected` will NOT be an instance of your class. I like to use interfaces, unless there is a specific reason needed to have a class, like class specific methods. You don't seem to have that, so I suggest you just use interfaces:

```ts
export interface School {
  s_name: string;
}

export interface Student {
  f: string;
  ff: School[];
}
```

If you want to have your data as classes though, remember when creating an instance of your class, you need to call `new Student({.....})`

As for the template... as earlier said, remove the outer `*ngFor` from template:

```html
<tr>
  <td>{{studentSelected.f}} :</td>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let s of studentSelected.ff">
    <td>{{s.s_name}}</td>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Your **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fukgxt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**